# DynamoDB update item condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am pretty new to DynamoDB and I cant find an answer to pretty trivial scenario.

Let's say I am aggregating user purchases using DynamoDB. So I store moneySpent per user per day and lastPurchaseTime. The problem is the purchase messages I receive are not guaranteed to be ordered by purchase time. So I want to always Add the newOrderPrice to moneySpent and update lastPurchaseTime only if it is greater than the current lastPurchase time.

So what I am . looking for is something like this:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'user_id': userId,
        'day': day
    },
    UpdateExpression="ADD moneySpent :moneySpent SET lastPurchaseTime = 
        MAX(lastPurchaseItem, :lastPurchaseTime)",
    expressionAttributeValues={
            ':moneySpent': moneySpent
            ':lastPurchaseTime': lastPurchaseTime
        }
    ReturnValues="NONE"
)
```

ConditionExpression don't help me Since conditionExpression is conditioning the whole expression.

The only solutions I came up with is storing a set of all purchase times and check the last purchase time when I query the data,

or perform two updates, one with a condition where lastPurchase > : lastPurchase and one with the opposite condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to this issue: 
[How to conditionally execute a SET operation in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709398/how-to-conditionally-execute-a-set-operation-in-dynamodb?rq=1)

I ended up doing two updates :(